# Convert grid in data to distance on a globe

Tags: python-3.x, datagrid, global

I want to try and calculate the distance between two grids (which might have some values in them (not important for now).

Suppose I have divided the entire globe into a grid size of 0.5 degree x 0.5 degree. I want to calculate the distance between them.

Look at this picture:
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/12/52/global-146441_960_720.png

It is quite evident that though the grid size (0.5 degree x 0.5 degree) is same across the globe the area covered by them is not. The grids near the poles are shorter and those at the equator are wider. So the distance from one grid to another must also be different.

I am quite confused sometimes about this idea. So when you download any meteorological data, they are categorized as grid size rather than pixel size, so calculating the distance is quite difficult as grids on the poles have shorter length while those on the equator have larger length.

Any more clarification can be asked if the question is not clear enough.
Thanks in advance!!